# Why does an exact duplicate question not appear in related questions?

Tags: discussion

I was browsing SO tonight and came across the following two identical questions (one was asked on SF and migrated to SO):

[Question asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200559/advantages-of-particular-do-while-macro-in-c)

[Migrated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200688/advantages-of-particular-do-while-macro-in-c)

As far as I can tell from searching here (questions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/related-questions-include-closed-questions)) the related questions section is generated on the fly, includes previously closed questions and is based on the text in the questions. Given those conditions they should appear in each other's related questions lists, shouldn't they?

Or is it the fact that the second one was migrated causes the related questions list to not contain the other question?

I would have thought if it was an on the fly generated list using a text match that an exact match would show up, even if it was posted later. I'm just curious, I don't know how often it's a problem or whether it's worth trying to do something to improve it. It looks a bit odd that one question got closed PDQ and the second one sails through with upvotes and plenty of answers.