# Don’t show (irrelevant) closed questions as “Related”

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, related-questions

I recently read (and posted an answer to) this U&L question: [file descriptor problem with looping bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/64112/23408) and saw [Loop examples in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19755/23408) in the “Related” column, so I clicked on it, only to discover that it was closed.  (To add insult to injury, its one answer could probably have been flagged as “Not a real answer”, except it’s not clear what that means when the question is “not a real question”.)  I suggest that closed questions should not be listed as “Related”.  After all, isn’t ***adding value*** the goal?

### At the very least, closed questions (or at least questions that are closed as “not a real question”) should be suffixed with “[closed]” in the “Related” list, as they are in the **All Questions** list.

Another approach would be to display the ***best*** (i.e., open, up-voted, answered) related questions in the “Related” list, and then put a “view more” link at the bottom that would expose the now witting user to the dregs.

Comment: @Wesley: Yes, that question is similar to mine.  _But it was never answered._  Refresh my memory: what’s the protocol to encourage the powers that be to respond to a year-an-a-half-old question?

Comment: Yeah sorry I shouldn't have close voted. The auto-generated text sure makes no sense "This question may already have an answer here"... (link to post with no answers). I don't think there's much that can be done, you just have to wait or provide a better case. See here too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/related-questions-include-closed-questions?rq=1

Comment: This is a great idea. Having valueless, answerless off topic questions as somehow "related" just makes it harder to find the posts that have applicability tot he problem at hand. I hope this gets implemented!

Comment: @Wesley: Yeah, I read several related questions before I posted mine.  I sort-of accept the argument that duplicate questions _might_ still have some value, but (a) no reason why they aren’t marked as such, (b) no reason why they aren’t buried under a “view more” link, like we have on our user pages (although I admit I didn’t see anybody suggesting that particular compromise solution), and (c) no argument to support keeping “narq” questions.  If we want to provide value to our users, and we ***throw information at them***, shouldn’t we do a better job of separating the wheat from the chaff?

Comment: @Scott: I totally agree, note that I'm the author of the suggested dupe! Maybe it would be helpful to focus on the labeling aspect: `How do I do XYZ? [closed]` ...but yeah - I don't think they should be displayed at all!

Comment: @Wesley: Seems like another case for [the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/195817).  :–)

Comment: @Scott: Haha I fully agree with that suggestion too! However, I was able to at least cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @Wesley: ISTR that the FAQ says, “We don’t run Meta Stack Overflow.  The community does.”  Hmmm.  Also amusing: I flagged the so-called answer on [_your_ question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100705/195817) as “not an answer”, and that was judged to be a “helpful flag”.  So now what do I do –– wait for that “answer” to be converted to a comment (or deleted), and then try my luck again?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot that post technically did have an answer. As far as "what to do": If you want to raise visibility on a feature request, you can post a bounty or add an answer to it (whcih will bump it to the front page). Answers on meta can usually be something like: *"I agree, and here's some other things to consider..."* or something like that. I'm sure the devs are busy so you'll have to be patient. The best you can do is gather support, refine the ideas, and wait for a decision to be made for better or worse.

Comment: @Wesley: Seems like a bug in the process of closing feature requests –– if it’s common for “answers” to be things like _“I agree, and here’s some other things to consider...”_ (things that would be comments on any of the main sites), then the fact that “This ‘question’ has been asked before and already has an answer” shouldn’t be a factor.  Oh well; the windmills are surrounding my castle; I’ve got to go fight them off.